# c# display windows form from console application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on console application , I have currently created a windows form (name:Fcon) in my project , are there any possible ways to display fcon from console ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest option is to start a windows forms project, then change the output-type to Console Application. Alternatively, just add a reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll, and start coding:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

[STAThread]
static void Main() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new Form()); // or whatever
}
```

The important bit is the [STAThread] on your Main() method, required for full COM support.

Another way :

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AllocConsole();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

If you research this topic , just on Google you can find so much way to implement your question : my suggest is to try some method and verify what is more adapt to you.

Comment: I once used the latter method where I created the console from the form, but that means that the form always tries to show.  Instead, I used a combination of both methods, where I allocate the console in the main OR run the form.  If I want the form to appear, I re-run myself via arg[0] with a window flag but that could also be done internally.

Answer (score 0):

i have found other solution

`testform tf = new testform();
 tf.Show();`

just created forms object in main